# Appium inspector crashes and won't load a certain page but can load other pages

Tags: appium

I'm trying to get the elements of a certain page and Appium inspector takes a long time to capture the picture, but then the elements page source will show up with only 1 element tag and rest of the elements are a blank page. Then clicking anywhere will be irresponsive because then the app would crash. I tried like 15 times to load this page, but it won't load and crashes the app. Appium inspector would get elements of other pages in the app though. Any ideas how to fix it?
Strange thing is on the ipad pro connected to my computer has no issues loading this page, but it is just the regular size ipad connected to the office automation rack which I screen share in has an issue.

Comment: I too facing the same issue

Comment: It turned out I needed to get a newer version of the build.